# How to correctly do the following: passing unique_ptr to lambda, then passing this lambda somewhere else

Tags: c++, lambda, unique-ptr, move-semantics

I have written this code, meaning that the lambda will own the unique pointer, but I also have to pass this lambda to other function to be called there.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void call(function<void()>&& f) {
    f();
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = make_unique<string>("hello\n");
    auto fn = [ptr = move(ptr)] () { cout << *ptr; };
    call(move(fn));
    return 0;
}
```

I got errors like

```
error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&)’
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Dp = std::default_delete<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
```

I'm looking for the way how to do what I need correctly.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/v5Ehrrd1T

Comment: Wait until C++23 and use `std::move_only_function`.

Comment: Since `std::function` should be copy constructible, then easiest way is to move `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` before passing it to function's closure. https://godbolt.org/z/zcn5xxecr

Answer (score 4):

The closure, lambda is not a `std::function<void()>`, this is the issue. The compiler needs to create a temporary `std::function<void()>`. The working code

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void call(auto&& f) {
    f();
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = make_unique<string>("hello\n");
    auto fn = [ptr = move(ptr)] () { cout << *ptr; };
    call(move(fn));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is that the lambda is not a `function<void()>`, then how come this example works if you use `make_shared` in place of `make_unique`?

Comment: Because `std::shared_ptr` is copyable and `unique_ptr` is not, and `std::function` can only type-erase a copyable callable object. The real question is here how to use type-erasure with a non-copyable closure. The answer is: you can't, you have to wait for `std::move_only_function`.

Comment: Agreed.  That would make a great addition to this answer.